# Defined Integral equation

Tags: integration

I've found this equation on a wall and I'm wondering if it is true and also what's the meaning of $\partial$ in the second member of the equation.

$$\int_N\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\omega=\int_{\partial N}\mathop{}\!\omega$$

Comment: $\partial N$ is the boundary of $N$. It's Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Well, at least *some* wall, *somewhere*, has righteous graffiti!  Bob Lewis, writing from Oakland, California.